# if else question mark in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an error with if else question mark in react.

```
  let skillSetStr = useSkillset(userInfo.Skills);
  // In some cases the db returns the userInfo in different objects.
  // For now this fixes the problem.
  if (userInfo.Skills === undefined) {
    skillSetStr = skillStr;
  }

        {skillSetStr ?
          <div className="user-preview-info">
            <div className="grid-item">Skillsets:</div>
            <div className="grid-item user-preview-info_data">
              {userInfo.Skills ?
                <div>
                  {userInfo.Skills.map(
                    (skillName, index) => <div key={index} className="user-skill"> {skillName.skill} </div>
                  )}
                </div>
                : <div>Unspecified</div>}
            </div>
          </div> : ""}
```

So in if else condition it's suppose return "Unspecified" for in but instead it's return null.

Here is how my project look like:
[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Its called a ternary operator and i m pretty sure the problem is in your outter "if else question mark"

Comment: Probably because `userInfo.Skills` is an array and an array is always _truthy_. Maybe checking for `userInfo.Skills.length` would work?

Comment: @thomas.winckell I mean not return but it should give me "Unspecified"

Comment: @EmileBergeron I tried `userInfo.Skills.length > 0 ? ...` it's giving me error `Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @NathanNguyen then use both checks: `userInfo.Skills && userInfo.Skills.length > 0`

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks Emile. I got it fixed. Can you write an answer so I can vote solved for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is saying that the array is undefined you can check it isn't empty before getting its length with "option chaining".

It would look like this:

`userInfo?.Skills?.length > 0` this removes the need to do two checks.